# How to hexlify protobuf's binary string in C++?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

For example, my protobuf message is

```
message Person {
  required string name=1;
}
```

If I use python:

```
import personinfo_pb2
person = personinfo_pb2.Person()
person.name="Houl"

packed_data = person.SerializeToString()
```

And I can print the hexlify data by:

```
print binascii.hexlify(packed_data)
```

I was wondering how to hexlify the  `SerializeToString` data in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement hex encoding yourself. For example one possible implementation could be:

```
string HexEscape(const string& buf) {
  string result(buf.size() * 3 + 1, '\0');
  const char hex[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

  for(size_t i = 0; i < buf.size(); ++i) {
    char* dest = &result[i*3];
    *dest++ = hex[(buf[i]>>4) & 0xF];
    *dest++ = hex[buf[i] & 0xF];
    *dest = ' ';
  }
  return result;
}
```